# Sort powershell hashtable by date property

Tags: powershell, sorting

I have a hashtable with about 1000 items with one of the property is a date

```
$ht=@{}
$ht[1]=@{Date="11/11/2021"; Number=03321}
$ht[2]=@{Date="10/10/2021"; Number=03321}
$ht[3]=@{Date="09/10/2021"; Number=03321}
# .....
```

An so on
I need to select 10 records with oldest date - any idea how I could do it?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how you came to this format, but in PowerShell is more common to have a list of `PSCustomObject`s also knowing that is usually the default input and oitput of cmdlets (including displaying).

Comment: Getting it from SharePoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would convert this Hashtable containing numbered hashtables into an array of PsCustomObjects, making sorting and selecting much easier:

```
$ht=@{}
$ht[1]=@{Date="11/11/2021"; Number=03321}
$ht[2]=@{Date="10/10/2021"; Number=03321}
$ht[3]=@{Date="09/10/2021"; Number=03321}

# convert to array of PsCustomObjects
$ht.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { [PsCustomObject]$_.Value } |
Sort-Object {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)} |
Select-Object -First 10
```

This will result in an array of objects, having properties `Number` and `Date`, sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

the following script is for ascending by date.If descending add -descending in sort-object, also please change your number of records in select-object

```
$ht=@{}
$ht[1]=@{Date="11/11/2021"; Number=03320}
$ht[2]=@{Date="10/10/2021"; Number=03321}
$ht[3]=@{Date="09/10/2021"; Number=03329}

$ht.GetEnumerator()| Sort-Object {$_.Value.Date} | Select-Object -First 2 | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Value.Date $_.Value.Number }
```

Comment: That seems to work, but if I try to create a new hash from "foreach": 
$h_fs=@{}
$h_free.GetEnumerator()| Sort-Object {$_.Value.ReleaseDate} |  ForEach-Object {  
   $tn=$_.Value;   $n=$tn.Number;   $h_fs["$n"]=@{Number=$n; ReleaseDate=$tn.ReleaseDate } ;
   Write-Host $n " - " $tn.ReleaseDate   
 }
I get list of "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry" instead of normal objects that can be refenced by $object.property ?

Comment: The above code is different from the given input, GetEnumerator will list the values. From there you can extract the values. Please refer @Theo answer , by using PSCustomObject it will be much more efficient and simple.